# Rails: Change "Choose file" to "Browse"

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, file-upload

I'm trying to make a file field for uploading images. However, mine has a "Browse" while a tutorial I'm watching has "Choose File".

My code for the file_field looks the same though. Can someone explain whether there's a difference? I'm trying to hook it up to AJAX to show my uploaded results without refreshing the page, so I'm not sure if that's possible with the "Browse" button.

my form:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @album, @photo], :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>

<%= f.file_field :avatar, multiple: true, name: "photo[avatar]" %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just the native OS part of selecting the file so you are likely just seeing differences between mac / linux / Windows.  Which are you on?  It should not affect the functionality you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

Its just a browser/os thing, you can change it with javascript/jquery by hiding the button and creating another, there are a number of techniques for this...

You should take a look at this railscast its a good way to upload files with [ajax/jquery](http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload)

Comment: i'm actually going through that tutorial right now!! that's why I asked, cuz his file field looks different from mine. thanks

Comment: can you explain how he shows the paintings through ajax though? I'm at the -7 minute mark (watched about six minutes) and he manages to show the paintings after refreshing the page, but his HTML is unclear since all he has is `<%= render @paintings %>` without ever showing his show page

Comment: he is appending a partial with that code, so he has a partial which has the code for one painting and its name or whatever and each time the upload is successful he renders the partial with that painting object.

Comment: ooo but 1. what does render @paintings do? I thought partials had to be named _partial_name.html.erb and not as an instance variable? 2. `$("#paintings").append("<%= j render(@painting) %>");` I don't understand what he is appending

Comment: its a shorthand syntax, so it will render _paintings assuming its an instance of the paintings model, check out this link on the rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials